# Pass custom options to a symfony2 form

Tags: forms, symfony

in symfony 1.4  it was possible to parameterize a form class definition, via the options of the form. Is there any way to pass custom options to my custom form type??? i've tried to use the options parameter of the `buildForm` method, but i'm not very sure what this array is, and apparently it is not for what i want... Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The solution is simple, if you want your custom option to be available also in Twig template, you must use 
`$builder->setAttribute()` in `buildForm` method
and 
`$view->set()` method in `buildView()` method, too.

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType as FormAbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

// For Symfony 2.1 and higher:
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

/**
 * ImagePreviewType
 *
 */
class ImagePreviewType extends FormAbstractType
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * For Symfony 2.0
     */
    //public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    //{
    //    $options = parent::getDefaultOptions($options);
    //    $options['base_path'] = 'path/to/default/dir/';
    //
    //    return $options;
    //}

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * For Symfony 2.1 and higher
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'base_path'         => '',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        // For Symfony 2.0:
        // $view->set('base_path', $form->getAttribute('base_path'));

        // For Symfony 2.1 and higher:
        $view->vars['base_path'] = $options['base_path'];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAttribute('base_path', $options['base_path'])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'image_preview';
    }

    public function getParent(array $options)
    {
        // for Symfony 2.0:
        // return 'field';

        // for Symfony 2.1 and higher:
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

Template for custom form type (file ...Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig):

```htm
{% block image_preview_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
<img src="{{ base_path ~ value }}" alt=""  {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }} />
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Register your template for custom form types in app/config/config.yml

```yml
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
        resources:
            - 'AcmeDemoAdminBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Usage: Display preview of user's image while editing his profile:

```php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Form/Type/UserType.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user_profile_image_file_name', new ImagePreviewType(), array(
            'base_path' => 'some/other/dir',
        ));
    }
}
```

**2014-08-18: Updated for Symfony 2.1 or higher**

Comment: i was missing the step with buildView for option passing to Twig! thank you!

Comment: What if I wanted to add an option to ALL form types (including default ones )? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: It's possible with the [Form Type Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html).

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE:** Please note that this solution only works in Symfony 2.0.x, which is obsolete, use `setDefaultOptions` instead of `getDefaultOptions`.

---

Justly, Symfony 2 form types accept options that you can use for anything you want inside the form type. You need to override `getDefaultOptions` method to specify your type options.

For example, I have a type `MyCustomType` that accept `my_option`, this option has a default value of `false`, the implementation of `MyCustomType` can be something like this.

```
class MyCustomType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        if($options['my_option']){
            //do something
        } else {
            //do another thing
        }
        ...
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'my_option' => false
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mycustomtype';
    }
}
```

Later, you will need to specify the option when you create the form in the controller, using the third parameter of `buildForm`:

```
$form = $this->buildForm(new MyCustomType(), null, array(
    'my_option' => true
));
```

If you not specify the `my_option` option, it takes the default value (`false`).

Comment: I tried this before asking here... but, as @jperovic says, it only supports a small set of predefined keys in the array of options... I have not tried his solution yet... but i'll just do it... thanks anyways!

Comment: This solution support any key that you want to use, you need simply override the `getDefaultOptions` method.

Comment: Maybe this answer is not suitable for author of question, but it has surely useful to me. Because of that, +1. :)

Comment: Haha... thanks, but I don't understand why my answer is not suitable for the question. The `$options` array passed to `buildForm` is used to pass custom options to the type. Then, based on this options you can set `Form` and/or `FormView` attributes to use the options in different places (a view for example) or wathever you want. Or maybe you can set view attributes without the need of any option. But the question was, "how pass options to a custom form type", maybe the question was not suitable for the author needs.

Comment: Apparently it's not with `getDefaultOptions()` anymore, but with `setDefaultOptions()`.

Otherwise it says 

`The option "no_animal_type" does not exist. Known options are:  "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", ...`

Comment: Apparently @Bonswouar has the right answer, helped by the shared knowledge of previous answers/comments. Thank you all (+1)

Answer (score 10):

Using symfony 2.8, I succeeded by using the proposed solution extending the `configureOptions()` method.

```php
class ElementType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'my_custom_option_parameter' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

I needed to use the `ElementType`, as a collection and embedded form. I  recognized that it was not possible to pass the `my_custom_option_parameter` to the `CollectionType`, because I did not customize `configureOptions()` of `CollectionType`, but of my `ElementType`. If you need to pass the `my_custom_option_parameter` through a `CollectionType`, you may succeed by defining `my_custom_option_parameter` in `entry_options` (see Documentation [CollectionType Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage)) array of `CollectionType`.

Example passing `my_custom_option_parameter` through a `CollectionType`:

```
class OuterFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    { 
        //...
        $builder->add('elements', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ElementType::class,
            // ...
            'entry_options' => array(
                'my_custom_option_parameter' => 'value is now set!'
            )
        ));
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

basing on @pulzarraider answer I created code with changes for Symfony 3.

You need to change

`OptionsResolverInterface` for `OptionsResolver`

`FormBuilder` for `FormBuilderInterface`

In my case:

```
namespace MediaBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType as FormAbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ImageType extends FormAbstractType {

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'max_images' => ''
        ));
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {

        $view->vars['max_images'] = $options['max_images'];
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
                ->setAttribute('max_images', $options['max_images'])
        ;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'image_preview';
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return TextareaType::class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Symfony 3, I was able to pass custom options to the form by setting a default option in the OptionsResolver injected into configureOptions method of my form type class:

In the Controller:

```
//Compile whatever your options are here. Assume an array is returned
$customOptions = $this->getMyCustomOptions($args);
//Build the form:
$form = $this->createForm(MyCustomFormType::class, array('my_custom_options' => $customOptions));
```

MyCustomFormType.php:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => DataModel::class,
        'my_custom_options' => []
    ]);
}
//custom options is now set in "$options" array:
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('my_custom_fields', Type\ChoiceType::class, [
       'choices' => $options['my_custom_options'],
       'mapped' => false //if not part of the data model.
       . . .
```

So, it looks like you can define a contract with your form and the data provider to set arbitrary data on the form.

I've just successfully implemented this procedure. Note that on the return trip, since you've set `'mapped' => false,` in the formBuilder, `$form->getData()` will not return the selection. To get the selected value:

```
$mySelectedValue = $form->get('my_custom_options')->getViewData();
```

in your controller. Why this is is beyond me . . .

Answer (score 2):

I have tried using that options `array` with no success as it seemed that it could carry only small, predefined subset of keys. This was, by all means, unacceptable for me...

However, you can pass all the options via forms `__construct` method and store it in class properties for later use. Then, from `buildForm` you can access it using `$this->"propertyName"`...

It's up to you to decide whether you want to pass single `array` or just few variables to `__construct`...

This is just a rough example:

```
class Foobar{
    private $update = false;

    public function __construct($update = false){
        $this->update = $update;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilder builder, array options){
        if ( $update ){
            // something
        }else{
            // well, this is not an update - do something else
        }
    }
}
```