# Is it possible to add extra string value to the form and then render it in template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it possible to add extra string value to the form and then render it in template like this:

form class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // add your custom field
    $builder->setSomeString('name', 'value');
```

template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
     {{ form_getSomeString('name')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass custom options to a symfony2 form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920006/pass-custom-options-to-a-symfony2-form)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set your values in the `buildView()` function (here is an [example](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php#L69) from the core) instead of `buildForm()`.

Then you have to override your form block in twig to access this value ([see documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field)).