# FOSUserBundle - Group assignment in UserType form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am creating a web interface that allows users to be assigned into groups with https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle and version 2.7 of Symfony on CentOS 6.x.

This is the code I have:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

/**
 * @Route("/admin/user")
 */
public function indexAction( Request $request )
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted( 'ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!' );

    $groups = $this->get('fos_user.group_manager')->findGroups();
    $groupNames = [];
    foreach ($groups as $g) {
        $groupNames[] = $g->getName();
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user_form = $this->createForm( new UserType(), $user );
    $user_form->add( 'groups', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $groupNames,
        'choices_as_values' => true,
        'multiple' => false
    ] );

    return $this->render( 'admin/user/index.html.twig', array(
                'user_form' => $user_form->createView(),
                'base_dir' => realpath( $this->container->getParameter( 'kernel.root_dir' ) . '/..' ),
            ) );
}
```

I've read the documentation at Symfony and Googled, but the debugger is throwing an error (*Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType"*).

I have two questions:

1. How can I add a choice field into the form that allows the user to select which groups to assign a user into?
2. Would it be better to add the group selection element into the UserType?

This is what I have for UserType (from following the Symfony docs):

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
                ->add( 'username' )
                ->add( 'email' )
                ->add( 'enabled', 'checkbox' )
                ->add( 'locked', 'checkbox' )
                ->add( 'expired', 'checkbox' )
                ->add( 'credentialsExpired', 'checkbox' )
        ;
    }
```

Thank you to @hendrathings for offering a much better solution than I had.

I upgraded to Symfony 3.0 to avoid version issues in the future.

This is what I finally implemented:

In **UserType.php**

```
// Additional dependencies ...

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $data )
    {
        $builder
                ->add( 'username', TextType::class )
                ->add( 'email', TextType::class )
                ->add( 'enabled', CheckboxType::class )
                ->add( 'locked', CheckboxType::class )
                ->add( 'groups', ChoiceType::class, [
                    'choices' => $data['group_names'],
                ] );
    }

    public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults( array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'group_names' => []
        ) );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

}
```

It is called from the controller like so:

```
    $groups = $this->get( 'fos_user.group_manager' )->findGroups();
    $groupNames = [];
    foreach( $groups as $g )
    {
        $groupNames[$g->getName()] = $g->getId();
    }
    $user = new User();
    $user_form = $this->createForm( UserType::class, $user, array( 'group_names' => $groupNames ));
```

This was also helpful: [Pass custom options to a symfony2 form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920006/pass-custom-options-to-a-symfony2-form)

I'm not entirely happy with my implementation, but I think I will leave it for now and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symfony version is 2.7 and you use symfony 3.0 syntax. Try upgrade your symfony by `composer`.

Or change this part `ChoiceType::class` to `choice`. and remove `use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType` as well.

1.How can I add a choice field into the form that allows the user to select which groups to assign a user into:

- Add new field `group` in `User` entity class
- Add `_construct` in `UserType` that pass of your `group` list (array)
- Add new field `group` in `UserType` form. and call `$this->group` to set `choiceType`
- Modify `controller` in `$this->createForm( new UserType(), $user );` to `$this->createForm( new UserType($group), $user );`

so your UserType would be:

```
private $group;

public function __construct($group)
{
    $this->group = $group;
}

public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
{
    $builder
            ->add( 'username' )
            ...
            ->add( 'group', 'choice', array(
                'choice' => $this->group
                ... // Your setting
            ))
    ;
}
```

Call your form in controller:

```
$this->createForm( new UserType($group), $user );
```

2. Yes. Make your code clean and understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have working now.

**Controller**

```
public function indexAction( Request $request )
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted( 'ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!' );

    $user_form = $this->createForm( UserType::class, null, [] );

    return $this->render( 'admin/index.html.twig', array(
                'user_form' => $user_form->createView(),
                'base_dir' => realpath( $this->container->getParameter( 'kernel.root_dir' ) . '/..' ),
            ) );
}
```

**UserType / Form**

```
public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
{

    $builder
            ->add( 'username', TextType::class )
            ->add( 'email', TextType::class )
            ->add( 'enabled', CheckboxType::class )
            ->add( 'locked', CheckboxType::class )
            ->add( 'groups', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Group',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'choices_as_values' => true,
                'expanded' => true
            ] );
}

public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
{
    $resolver->setDefaults( array(
        'groups' => [],
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
    ) );
}
```