# Symfony: how to get a parameter from the route within a FormType?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to access the parameter `page` from the current route within a `FormType`. It works in a `Controller`, but not in a `FormType`. I'd like to avoid passing the parameter like `/?page=1` and prefer `/page/1`.

**routing.yml**

```
my_route:
    path: /data/page/{page}
    defaults:
        _controller: MyBundle:MyController:myAction
```

**src/myBundle/Form/Type/MyFormType.php**

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType {
    // ...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $page    = $request->query->get('page');
        echo "page: $page"; // empty

        // ...
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid to pass the parameter through the Controller to the FormType and prefer to access it directly within the FormType.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** 
Regarding the selected answer; the `page` **attribute** is accessible via `$request->attributes->get('page')`, not via `$request->query->get('page')`.

Comment: If you have the FormType bypass the Controller and pull the variable from the global variables, you're defeating the purpose of using a FormType (instead of just building the form directly in your action in the Controller). FormTypes allow you to reuse the form in multiple contexts -- you won't be able to reuse this FormType on any route that doesn't have that same path variable.

Comment: @HaydenSchiff Good point and I actually agree with you, but in my current case it's an optional way to set a default form structure. If the route has the parameter, the FormType hides a field and sets it's value. If not, the field is visible and the user has to select/insert the value. The example above is just to keep it simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject the request stack service into form type to do that:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType 
{
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    } 

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        //do something: for example hide/show fields from request parameters  
    }
}
```

Register the form type and their dependencies:

```
services:
    app.form.type.myform:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\MyFormType
        arguments: ['@request_stack']
        tags:
           - { name: form.type }
```

---

However, is recommended instead to create the new option to pass all variables that you need for your form type.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly what I needed. The parameter I was looking for, in my example `page`, is now accessible like this: `$request->attributes->get('page')`.

Comment: You should avoid passing extra parameters to your form type using a constructor, check the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure the answer provided by Yonel is the best because you inject a dependency to your form.
It has some drawbacks and the major one IMHO is that it will make the test difficult as the dependency on the page parameter is hidden.

A better solution will be to add it as form option to your form.

The request object is already available in your controller and you are probably creating your form this way :

```
$form = $this->createForm(WhateverFormType::class, $entity)
```

Using the createForm method, you can inject a third argument which are the options (i.e additional data) you want to pass to your form.

So in your controller :

```
$page = $request->query->get('page');
$form = $this->createForm(WhateverFormType::class, $entity, ['page' => $page]);
```

And in your form type, follow the example given in this answer for the same question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10922788/2721918

Comment: Best answer IMHO, straightforward solution

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to inject the request stack service in the construct of your formtype. You can access to the requestStack by using form event listener like that:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
$form = $event->getForm();
$form->getConfig()->getRequestHandler();
// do what you need...
});
```