# FOS Symfony 4 can't pass current user to registration form type

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony4

I have function in repository with parameter. Can't pass this parameter from FOSUser bundle controller -> FormType -> Repository.

I try use $option like in this topic - [Pass custom options to a symfony2 form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920006/pass-custom-options-to-a-symfony2-form)
and pass $this->getUser(); but this not work for me. Can't set or get this data. Probably i doing somethink wrong.

Function in repository:

```
public function getRanksWithYourPrivilages($id = 1) {
    $queryBuilder =  $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $ranks = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App:RanksRows')->getRankListWithYourPrivilages($id);
    $ranks = implode(",",$ranks);
    return $queryBuilder->select('r')
            ->from(Ranks::class,'r')
            ->where('r.id IN ('.$ranks.')');
}
```

RegistrationFormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    //var_dump($options);
    $builder
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'options' => array(
                'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                'attr' => array(
                    'autocomplete' => 'new-password',
                ),
            ),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
        ->add('rank', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Ranks::class,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->getRanksWithYourPrivilages();
            },
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            ))
    ;
}
```

RegistrationController:

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
    $user->setEnabled(true);

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $form = $this->formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

        if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            return $response;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```